# Guest Password From Bigger Database in Moodle

Tags: mysql, moodle

I want to write or edit guest password feature in moodle 2.6.
I have created database table with 10 codes:

```
123456
123675
code3
code4
code5
code6
code7
code8
code9
code10
```

When I'm creating a lesson in moodle I want to always have 'allow guest' option turned on. 
After I create a lesson everyone who have 1 of my codes have access to lesson. I think it would be really helpful if I have a lot of students and don't want to send to everyone an e-mail with code.
Can somebody tell me where I can find sql to guestpassword checking in moodle 2.6 ? If I find it i think that after I only to have to simply check if code is in my table and give permission to see lesson or not.

Best Regards
Thanks For Help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question but there is already an allow guest access with a password option for each course already in Moodle.

First go to site admin -> plugins -> enrolments -> manage plugins.

Ensure that both the self enrolment and guest access plugins are enabled.

Then go to your course and edit the course settings -> go to the guest access section -> select yes for guest access and enter a password to access the course.

Then when a guest user tries to access the course, they can click the login as guest button and will then be asked for the password to view the course.

http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/Guest_access#Course_settings_for_guest_access